# React table with mui - mui kitchen sink example - switching JSON and makeDATA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-table

i'm tryning to play with the react table mui kitchen sink and do not understand why the value aren't visible . the Header is visible when switching to JSON it's the data in the table not visible anymore. on the console.log, data and data1 have the same structure.

```
      const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => [
          {
            Header: 'ID',
            accessor: 'id',
          },
          {
            Header: 'LICENSE PLATE',
            accessor: 'licenseplate',
          },
          {
            Header: 'DRIVER NAME',
            accessor: 'driver',
          },
          {
            Header: 'SUBMITTED ON',
            accessor: 'submittionDate',
          },
          {
            Header: 'NOTES',
            accessor: 'notes',
          },
          {
            Header: 'STATUS',
            accessor: 'status',
          },
        ],
        []
      )
     const NoteList = Object.keys(NOTES).map(key => ({ ...NOTES[key], id: key }))
      const [data1, setData1] = React.useState(React.useMemo(() => makeData(10), []))
      const [data, setData] = React.useState(React.useMemo(() => NoteList), [])
      const [skipPageReset, setSkipPageReset] = React.useState(false)
    
    
      useEffect(() => {
        // This gets called after every render, by default
        // (the first one, and every one after that)
        // console.log('NOTES', NOTES);
        // console.log('NOTESLIST', NoteList);
        console.log('DATA', data);
        console.log('DATA1', data1);
    
      }, [])
```

i don't know where's the mistake.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

After some hours, the mistake has been solved.

The accessor name has to match the name attribute in the json file. And there's no need to use the `object.key` function. the use of `useMemo` is enough.